# remove file from url with urlrewritefilter

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a URL like `www.foo.com/start/rewrite.php/home/say/index`

How can use UrlRewriteFilter to remove the rewrite.php from this URL e.g.

```
www.foo.com/start/home/say/index
```

i think mod_rewrite will work with

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/start/rewrite.php/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
<rule>
    <from>^(.*)/(rewrite.php)/(.*)$</from>
    <to>$1/$3</to>
</rule>
```